# Solving programmatically a least squares problem with one constrain

Tags: optimization, least-squares, constraint-programming

I need to solve the following problem (preferably in python but any other suggestion is welcome)

$$
\min_x||Ax - b||_2
$$
$$
s.t. \: Dx = Dy
$$

everything except x is known. $A$ and $D$ are square sparse matrices, $x$,$y$ and $b$ are vectors. From what I understand, without the constrain the problem is solvable using the pseudo-inverse, however I am having trouble incorporating the constrain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is given by:

$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\arg \min_{x} & \quad & \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} \\
\text{subject to} & \quad & D x = e
\end{alignat*}
$$

Where $ e = D y $.

The Lagrangian is given by:

$$ L \left( x, \nu \right) = \frac{1}{2} \left\| A x - b \right\|_{2}^{2} + {\nu}^{T} \left( D x - e \right) $$

From KKT Conditions the optimal values of $ \hat{x}, \hat{\nu} $ obeys:

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} A & {D}^{T} \\ 
D & 0
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
\hat{x} \\ 
\hat{\nu}
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
{A}^{T} b \\ 
e
\end{bmatrix} $$

Now all needed is to solve the above with any Linear System Solver.

Answer (score 1):

There is a solution to your problem:

http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~ee127a/book/login/l_ols_variants.html

To bring your problem to the form they are using, replace $Dy$ by some vector.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately my D matrix is too big to estimate its null space. Is there an alternative maybe using frobenius norms and the pseudo-inverse?

Comment: What are the dimensions of $x$, $A$ and $D$?

Comment: Moreover, do you use matlab or python to solve the problem?